# Add to cart button is disabled in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

I have Prestashop 1.7 and I have the problem that when I add the option to add a customization to the product, it disables the add to cart button, and it shows no error at all.

[image]

When I click the red button at the bottom it does nothing, and the yellow button it takes me directly to the cart page, but it is empty.

This only happens to productos that has the customization option enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed the position of

```
                    {if $product.is_customizable && count($product.customizations.fields)}
                {block name='product_customization'}
                {include file="catalog/_partials/product-customization.tpl" customizations=$product.customizations}
                {/block}
                {/if}
```

in the product.tpl?

I have the very same problem. Couldn't figure out how to fix it and ended up just putting it back below

```
    <div class="product-information">
                {block name='product_description_short'}
                <div id="product-description-short-{$product.id}" class="product-desc" itemprop="description">{$product.description_short nofilter}</div>
                {/block}
```

In that position of the product.tpl file, everything works for me.

Comment: The customization part was outside the form, and this was causing the problem. Thanks for the answer